# value of $L(1,\chi_{9529})$ and Littlewood's bound

Tags: nt.number-theory

Consider a quadratic field ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt d)$ and its
$L$-function, evaluated at 1.  Littlewood proved a famous bound (under GRH) and it's known that for infinitely many $d$, half this bound is exceeded.  Now for some $d$, the negative pell equation is solvable (or otherwise put, the period of the continued fraction of $\sqrt d$ is odd).  And my question is, can any of THESE $d$  be among the ones whose L-function exceeds half Littlewood's bound?   So I looked by computer and found just one candidate,  $d = 9529$.  I compute
$$ L(d)/ \log \log d = 1.783869 $$
while half of Littlewood's bound (divided by $\log\log d$) is
$$ e^{\gamma} =1.781072.$$
So if the computation is right, this example refutes the conjecture that if negative Pell is solvable, then Littlewood's bound can be cut in half;  or in other words, the  $d$ with $L$ exceeding half the bound can't have negative Pell solvable.  But it's just wrong in the third decimal place,  so possibly I have not computed L correctly. (I just added up ten thousand (or more) terms of the
Dirichlet series, using the algorithm for Kronecker symbols from Cohen's book.)  How can I check this L-value some other way?  And what do you experts say about the empirical fact that all the other $d$ with large $L$ have even period?

Comment: $L(d)/\log(\log(d))=1.7839076999499...$, done with Pari/GP but many other packages will give you that result.

Comment: Upon looking at larger d,  I found many more examples; moreover, I overlooked 8089 and 8761.    After a while there tend to be one or two per thousand $d$-values.   I would mark Cohen's comment as an answer, but I don't think I'm allowed to mark a comment as an answer (?)